# ClientWebSocket wss - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, websocket

I have created a WebSocket server in NodeJs and hosted it on GCP. The URL for the server is wss://scramblegram.bluemsoftware.com

I created a WebSocket client using ClientWebSocket C# core 5.0.

Here is my issue

If I connect to wss://scramblegram.bluemsoftware.com using my client ClientWebSocket I get "Unable to connect to the remote server"

If I connect to wss://scramblegram.bluemsoftware.com using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html it works perfectly.

If I connect to wss://echo.websocket.org using my client ClientWebSocket it works perfectly.

can someone explain what is going on and how I can debug and solve this? It makes no sense

[Edit]
Code
https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket/blob/master/NativeWebSocket/Assets/WebSocket/WebSocket.cs

> WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("wss://scramblegram.bluemsoftware.com");
> await ws.Connect();

Answer (score 0):

Kindly post the code to your Custom C# Web Socket client...
We cannot try to help without seeing your code.

Ok so many things might be wrong. It might be that the remote host is behind a **firewall** that's blocking your web socket client machine...
Or TLS version issues. So many things can be wrong. So it's hard to tell.

I will also suggest if you check message and it's not informative enough, try checking the Github page of that Web socket client that you are using for issues related.

**But most likely, the remote firewall is blocking requests from your local machine.**

That's my thought.

Comment: I am using this library which internally uses ClientWebSocket https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket/blob/master/NativeWebSocket/Assets/WebSocket/WebSocket.cs

Comment: I thought about the firewall issue. But it still does not make sense. How can the firewall be blocking my connection but it works fine when I connect to my server using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

As for TLS version. I check the TLS version on Wireshark between a client that can connect and a client that can't. And the TLS version is identical which is 1.2

Comment: Well that means it's not blocking websocket.org/echo.html    This is not logical but try turning off your local machine's firewall and try again.